# Classic ASP app unable to create oracle session in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently trying to get an application working which reads data from an oracle database on the network. This was previously hosted on IIS 6 Windows server 2003.

When I try to log in to the application it needs to read from the oracle database but I get the following error when it tries to connect.

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0134'
Invalid ProgID attribute
/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/NETEXPLORERAPP/global.asa, line 1
The object has an invalid ProgID of 'OracleInProcServer.XOraSession'.
```

From what I've read so far this is due to missing dlls and the way to add them is to install Oracle Objects for OLE. When I tried to install them I got an "unexpected internal error" from the Oracle installer. I'm not sure if this will actually resolve the issue though as I haven't had to do this in the past and the issue this fix was for wasn't identical to mine.

Comment: Yes, it is an issue with the OLE objects not being present (or incorrectly registered) so you need to address the install problem.  Looking for any install logs/event viewer messages would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the Oracle Client on the web server so that your code has access to the proper registered DLLs. Once you do that, the problem will go away.

Comment: do you specifically have to choose to install oo4o? I'm not doing the installation myself so i'm not sure what the process looks like. Would there be any issue installing this on windows server 2012?

Comment: I'm not sure what oo4o is, as I'm no Oracle expert. However, I do remember running into this error years ago when I was working with ASP w/ an Oracle backend, and there was an option in the installer to install the oracle client. As for the official term of what it is called, I don't remember offhand, but it should be pretty straightforward on what it is. As for if it's ok to install on Windows 2012, yes it is ok, whatever the req for oracle are in terms of the OS is the same as setting it up using ASP.